# MYSQL select where count > 1

Tags: mysql, count

Need to execute query to find rowns with 3rd column value count > 1. Example:

Table:

```
     col1   col2    col3  
------------------------  
1.   val1   val2    val3
2.  val11  val21    val3
3.  val12  val22   val31
4.  val13  val23   val32
5.  val14  val24   val32
```

Result will be rows 1,2,4,5 because we have values in col3 with count > 1

Answer (score 10):

Your question is very unclear, this is probably what you're asking:

```
SELECT COUNT(col3) as countCol3
FROM table
GROUP BY col3
HAVING countCol3 > 1
```

Comment: Not the down-voter, but the OP seems to be asking for the rows, not (just) the count. While this query is a hint to getting an answer for the OP, it does not provide a complete answer (at least how I interpret the question, and I may be wrong ^^)

Comment: @jswolf19 I see your point. However, as you can imagine I am not willing to give a full detailed answer to someone who does't ask a full detailed question. The question doesn't provide with any primary keys, or nothing that could be used to retrieve the full row in a decent manner.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer that could help you. I have included some sample data to help others who would find some example data helpful:

```
drop table if exists valTable;

create table valTable
(
id int unsigned primary key auto_increment not null,
col1 varchar(50),
col2 varchar(50),
col3 varchar(50)
);

insert into valTable (col1,col2,col3) values ('val1','val2','val3');
insert into valTable (col1,col2,col3) values ('val11','val21','val3');
insert into valTable (col1,col2,col3) values ('val12','val22','val31');
insert into valTable (col1,col2,col3) values ('val13','val23','val32');
insert into valTable (col1,col2,col3) values ('val14','val24','val32');

select vt.*
from valTable vt
where vt.col3 in
(select col3Multi from (
select col3 col3Multi,count(*) as c
from valTable
group by col3
having c > 1) t );
```